# How to know when a file has been sunk on HDFS using Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm downloading a file source and creating and stream to process line by line to finally sink into HDFS.
For that purpose I'm using Spring Cloud Dataflow + Kafka.

Question: is there any way to know when the complete file has been sunk into HDFS to trigger an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to know when the complete file has been sunk into HDFS to trigger an event?

This type of use-case typically falls under task/batch as opposed to streaming pipeline. If you build a `filehdfs` task (*batch-job*) application, you could then have a stream listening to various task-events in order to make further downstream decisions or data processing.

Please refer to "[Subscribing to Task/Batch Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task-events)" from the reference guide for more details.